# Why cant i Add a pin to my map Google Map API

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-api

This is my typescript code for adding a pin, Ive followed tutorials and read other stackoverflow questions but there just not working can anyone see anything im doing wrong or what im missing?

TS:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    // disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom:14,
    // styles: [                   //Hides Landmarks
    //   {
    //     featureType: 'poi',
    //     stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }],
    //   },
    // ],
  };


  ngOnInit() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.center = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };
    });
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: { lat: 53.280040911392774, lng: -9.010356288290776 },
          zoom: 14,
      });

    // const myLatLng = { lat: 53.280040911392774, lng: -9.010356288290776 };

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: 53.280040911392774, lng: -9.010356288290776 },
      title: "PARK",
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="area">
  <div class="position">
    <google-map
      height="60vh"
      width="100%"
      [center]="center"
    ></google-map>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Map: (Marker should be in the center)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not added the *map-marker* element inside the *google* element. Here is an example of how it should look like:

**html**

```
<google-map 
    height="100%" 
    width="100%" 
    [center]="center" 
    [zoom]="zoom" 
    [options]="options">
    <map-marker  
        [position]="center" 
        [options]="markerOptions">
    </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

**.ts**

```
zoom = 10;
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;  // set this equal to position and give both to marker and map
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 6,
  };
  pos = { lat: -34.075023, lng: 18.844073 };  // position of the map and the marker
  markerOptions = { animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP };
```